# how to run program when the start script is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When I am trying to run my code using npm start I am getting this error -

npm start -

npm ERR! Missing script: "start"

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?

npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages

npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites

npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:

npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-20T08_18_49_238Z-debug-0.log

Comment: your might not have defined a `start` script in your `package.json` file, you could start by doing `node your-script.js`

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to define the start script in the package.json file. For example here in this node project
package.json (remove the comment to use the json):

```
{
  "name": "node-starter",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js" // <-- start script here to start a node program
  }
}
```

Full example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-g7ntls?file=index.js,package.json

Answer (score 0):

You can use like node entry.js